# Error on see my profile

Tags: bug, 500-server-error

Well, I try to help, while navigate between statistical profiles, I did click on my face button and see the page below...

[image]

Comment: No repro for me. I'm on chrome / Win10 in case that matters.

Comment: What page were you on before you got this error? Can you give a link?

Comment: I've been getting a lot of errors on SE in the past hour, just got a 503 a minute ago and I had a maintenance message earlier. Nick_Craver says on twitter "Today is not going well."

Comment: I think we can safely put this one on wonky EF Core stuff.